# Installing Vim with python 2 and 3 on CentOS; Python 3 version is too old

Tags: python, vim, configure

I'm trying to compile Vim from source with both python2 and python3 support on CentOS because the Black formatter requires python3. I'm following the YouCompleteMe guide for it (https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Building-Vim-from-source). But ./configure fails saying python3 is too old. It seems confused about which binary to run maybe, even though I'm supplying that.

I have python3.6 installed alonside several other versions. I read that Debian can't install Vim with both alongside each other but RHEL wasn't mentioned.

This is my ./configure command:

```
./configure --with-features=huge \
        --enable-multibyte \
        --enable-rubyinterp=yes \
        --enable-pythoninterp=yes \
        --with-python-command=python2.7 \
        --with-python-config-dir=/usr/lib64/python2.7/config \
        --enable-python3interp=yes \
        --with-python3-config-dir=/usr/lib64/python3.6/config-3.6m-x86_64-linux-gnu \
        --with-python3-command=python3.6 \
        --enable-gui=gtk2 \
        --enable-cscope \
        --prefix=/usr/local \
        --enable-fail-if-missing \
```

./configure fails with this result:

```
checking Python version... (cached) 2.7
checking Python is 2.3 or better... yep
checking Python's install prefix... (cached) /usr
checking Python's execution prefix... (cached) /usr
(cached) checking Python's configuration directory... (cached) /usr/lib64/python2.7/config
(cached) checking Python's dll name... (cached) libpython2.7.so.1.0
checking if -pthread should be used... yes
checking if compile and link flags for Python are sane... yes
checking --enable-python3interp argument... yes
checking --with-python3-command argument... python36
checking Python version... (cached) 2.7
checking Python is 3.0 or better... too old
configure: error: could not configure python3
```

So... how do I fix this and make it work?

Comment: Your python3 dir is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Install devel packages for python3

```
yum install python3-devel*
```